# echo full command to file

Tags: bash, echo

I have the following command

```
echo “more PHONEBOOK.lst | awk '!/ NY /' | sort -k1 | sort -k4 | tee PHONENOTNY.LST” >> NOTNY.sh && chmod 0777 NOTNY.sh
```

However when I run the command and view the content of NOTNY.sh it contains

```
“more PHONEBOOK.lst
```

It should contain

```
more PHONEBOOK.lst | awk '!/ NY /' | sort -k1 | sort -k4 | tee PHONENOTNY.LST
```

How do I copy the text from the command and not the result I am getting?

Comment: I'm guessing those are "smart" quotes, which your shell saw as just more bytes instead of actual quotes.

Comment: How do I make it see the command as a whole and not evaluate the command?

Comment: *Quote* the string. Your example contains the characters `“` and `”` (U+201C and U+201D) which *are not quotes* as far as the shell is concerned. The shell understands `'` (U+0027) and `"` (U+0022). The fancy curly characters featured in your example are just ordinary fancy curly characters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of “smart” quotes, use normal "double-quotes":

```
printf "%s\n" "more PHONEBOOK.lst | awk '!/ NY /' | sort -k1 | sort -k4 | tee PHONENOTNY.LST" >> NOTNY.sh && chmod 0777 NOTNY.sh
```

Or, saving a pointless call to `more`, since awk will read the files you tell it to:

```
printf "%s\n" "awk '!/ NY /' PHONEBOOK.lst | sort -k1 | sort -k4 | tee PHONENOTNY.LST" >> NOTNY.sh && chmod 0777 NOTNY.sh
```

Or, since the second `sort` will just override the first one:

```
printf "%s\n" "awk '!/ NY /' PHONEBOOK.lst | sort -k4 | tee PHONENOTNY.LST" >> NOTNY.sh && chmod 0777 NOTNY.sh
```